# Does std::sort check if a vector is already sorted?

Tags: c++, sorting, gcc, c++11, stl

I believe that the C++ standard for [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) does not guarantee O(n) performance on a list that's already sorted. But still, I'm wondering whether to your knowledge any implementations of the STL (GCC, MSVC, etc) make the [`std::is_sorted`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted) check before executing the sort algorithm?

Asked another way, what performance can one expect (without guarantees, of course) from running `std::sort` on a sorted container?

Side note: I posted [some benchmarks](http://lexfridman.com/blogs/research/2011/07/04/sorting-a-sorted-list-in-c/) for GCC 4.5 with C++0x enabled on my blog. Here's the results:

[image: Comparison of std::sort and std::is_sorted]

Comment: would like to see on a log-log scale

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Implementations are free to use any efficient sorting algorithm they want so this is highly implementation dependant

However I have seen a performance comparison of `libstdc++` as used on linux and against `libc++` the new C++ library developed by Apple/LLVM. Both these libraries are very efficient on sorted or reverse sorted data (much faster than on a random list) with the new library being considerable faster then the old and recognizing many more patterns.

To be certain you should consider doing your own benchmarks.

Comment: A few months ago I asked Howard Hinnant how he implemented the `std::sort` in libc++. His implementation does check for sorted and reverse-sorted inputs, not only at the "full" level, but also at each level of the recursion, so that partially sorted inputs also benefit from the speed-up. He believed it was important enough to sacrifice some performance in the "chaotic" case.

Comment: The STL available with msvc 2010 (Dinkumware, I think) also does something similar to what Matthieu mentions. It's not the same as calling `is_sorted` on the inputs, but rather builds a check for partially sorted sub-ranges into the quicksort partition, hence useful for partially sorted sequences.

Comment: Clarification.  libc++ doesn't not actually do an `is_sorted` check at each level (which would burn up too much cpu).  But it is close to that.  I believe libc++ does 2N comparisons (and no swaps) on a sorted sequence (`is_sorted` only does N comparisons on a sorted sequence).  libc++ counts swaps during each partition phase.  If there are no swaps done, then libc++ switches to a "partial" insertion sort for each partition.  This insertion sort will abort if more than a few elements need to be inserted.  Recall that insertion sort does only N comparisons (and no moves) for a sorted sequence.

Comment: -1: Actually, implementations must provide an `std::sort` with `Complexity: Approximately N log N (where N == last - first) comparisons on the average.` (25.3.1.1 _Sorting_ [lib.sort]), so the set of allowed sorting functions is limited.

Comment: @phresnel, that's right but I didn't think it an important details as it should be obvious that implementers would vary the algorithm to get the best speed possible and not to make it slow.

Comment: @Eelke: Of course they are free to vary, but within a _non_ -infinite set of algorithms, and I am afraid that invalidates the your phrase _"Implementations are free to use any sorting algorithm they want so this is highly implementation dependant"_.

Comment: @phresnel: ok changed it to "any efficient algorithm".

Comment: @Eelke: For a sorted list, a bubble-sort is pretty _efficient_ (O(n)). Yet the standard does not allow it as the underlying algorithm for `std::sort`.

Comment: @phresnel You are acting like an ignoramus. For anyone with an education the default meaning of "efficient sort" is O(N log N) comparisons. The standard itself doesn't mention what we are averaging over for the "on the average" part - a competent practitioner is expected to know that. The same for "efficient" in Eelke's answer. (N.B. in C++14 it is no longer an average case complexity, but a worst-case.)

Comment: @Eponymous: For anyone with a job, the "default meaning" does not matter w.r.t. the actual business case. Different problems require different algorithms. If my business requirement is "need to get this done within 2 hours", yes, I can fall back to what you consider "default meaning". If my business requirement is "for each of the 1700 customers, compute the ordered Top 5 (out of billion) of their tracking-codes twice per second", your default meaning is naught. If my problem is to get a sale, a competent human is expected to not fall back to name calling, btw.

Comment: @Eponymous That's not very kind and it's not very fair. We deal in precise language here, and the language of this answer is not sufficient, particularly for "competent practitioners". Phrasing it as "any sufficiently efficient algorithm" would be better but then that's still misrepresenting what complexity requirements actually mean. Ultimately it would be very easy to get this sentence right by just saying what the actual requirements _are_: _"Implementations are free to use any sorting algorithm with complexity of, or better than, approx O(NlogN) comparisons"_ #problemsolved

Answer (score 24):

**No**. Also, it's not logical to have `is_sorted()` called for any STL implementation. Since, `is_sorted()` is available already as a stand-alone. And many users may not want to waste execution cycles unnecessarily to call that function when they already know that their container is not sorted.

STL also should be following the C++ philosophy: "**pay per use**".

Comment: What do you mean by "pay per use"?

Comment: @Lex Fridman: it means that something costs _only_ if you use it. `std::sort` wouldn't call `std::is_sorted` because then `std::sort` would incur the costs of `std::is_sorted` in addition to its own. That is, if you want to prevent possibly NlogN for `std::sort`ing a sorted list, it is up to _you_ to pay the price of calling `std::is_sorted`. Besides, if you have lists that are nearly-sorted, you should be using a bubble sort or something else that has good sorting characteristics for nearly sorted lists.

Comment: @Lex, in Bjarne Stroustrup's words, `"Pay only for what you use."` I don't recall in which interview he said this. But this phrase is easily available on net.

Comment: @Lex: it's a guiding concept in C++ language evolution... same for things like exceptions, virtual dispatch, availability of `std::vector::operator[]` vs `at()`...

Comment: @Billy: An already sorted list is O(n) for bubble sort. (If nothing moves during a specific iteration of the sort then there is no point in repeating the bubble on the next element and you can quit early). In the general case though it is O(n^2).

Comment: @Martin: An already sorted list is O(n) for several sorts, most of which perform MUCH better than bubble sort. For example, insertion sort. (Quicksort can be written this way but I don't think most common implementations are....)

Comment: @Billy ONeal : There are reasonable definitions of "nearly sorted" for which bubble sort is the best algorithm. The trivial case is a list which is sorted except for two adjacent elements.

Comment: @Billy: and that is why the original comment also mentions other sorts **<quote>using a bubble sort or something else that has good sorting characteristics</quote>**. It is the way **you** phrased your exclamation it seemed like you doubted bubble sort had good characteristics for nearly sorted lists.

Comment: @MSalteres: Theoretically, yes. But if someone is seriously using Bubble Sort in production code I think there's a problem. (And more importantly, Insertion Sort performs well for that single swapped case too) @Martin: Fair enough.

Comment: Good points; Minor meta-critic: a) The canonical C++ way of stating "pay per use" is "Only pay for what you use" b) for the most part, the STL and other parts of the library DO follow that philosophy

Answer (score 12):

Wow!  Did you have optimizations all the way cranked up?

[image: Here's] the results of your code on my platform (note the values on the vertical axis).

Comment: Cool, you're right, I didn't turn on optimization. The question is updated. Still it looks like for you, std::sort is doing much better than for me. I wonder why?

Comment: See the third comment under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567326/does-stdsort-check-if-a-vector-is-already-sorted/6567699#6567699

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you read [this comparison of sorting algorithms](http://warp.povusers.org/SortComparison/integers.html), it is very well done and informative, it compares a number of sorting algorithms with each other and with GCC's implementation of std::sort. You will notice, in the charts on the given link, that the performance of std::sort for "almost sorted" and "almost reverse" are linear in the number of elements to sort, that is, O(n). So, no guarantee, but you can easily expect that an almost sorted list will be sorted in almost linear-time. But, of course, it does not do a is_sorted check, and even if it will sort a sorted array in linear-time, it won't be as fast as doing a is_sorted check and skipping the sorting altogether. It is your decision to determine if it is better to check before sorting or not.

Answer (score 4):

The standard sanctions only `std::sort` implementations with complexity O(n log n):

> **Complexity:** Approximately N log N (where `N == last - first`) comparisons on the average.

See section ***25.3.1.1 Sorting [lib.sort]*** (ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E)).

Thus, the set of allowed sorting functions is limited, and you are right that it does not guarantee linear complexity.

> [Ideal behavior for a sort is O(n), but this is not possible in the average case.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

Of course the average case is not necessarily the exact case you have right now, so for corner cases, there's not much of a guarantee.

Comment: the problem is - depending on the algorithm, a sorted vector might present the worst case. O(n log n) on average does not say anything about the worst case - so it can be O(n^2) as it is for standard quicksort.

Answer (score 1):

And why would any implementation do that check? What would it gain? -- Nothing in average. A good design rule is not to clutter implementation with optimizations for corner cases which make no difference in average. This example is similar to check for self-assignment. A simple answer: don't do it.

Comment: Your "on average" case only works if your input is uniformly distributed over the possible inputs (i.e. all possible permutations). However, with many applications, this is not the case. Also, the same code that prevents ordinary quick-sort from falling down into square complexity usually helps with almost-sorted sequences, so you usually kill two birds with one stone.

Comment: Also, not checking for self-assignment is can often be an error in C++. So do do it! (unless you know it's not an error to omit).

Comment: @ltjax: not really, the optimization for corner cases is often another *root of all evil in programming*. Regarding self-assignment: **avoid writing a copy assignment operator that relies on a check for self-assignment in order to work properly; often, that reveals a lack of error safety** -- Herb Sutter

Comment: I agree that optimization for corner cases is bad. But somewhat sorted input is not a corner case. Input to sorting functions is usually not very random at all.

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee that it'll check this. Some implementations will do it , others probably won't.

However, if you suspect that your input might already be sorted (or nearly sorted), `std::stable_sort` might be a better option.

Comment: Do you have evidence to support the claim that stable sort might be better there?

Comment: `std::sort` is intended to be implemented as quicksort. And quicksort (in some implementations) exhibits worst-case (O`n^2)`behavior on sorted input. `stable_sort` is intended to be implemented as heapsort or mergesort, which provide stricter worst-case guarantees

Comment: @jalf: The worst case scenario for quicksort is for a naïve implementation of quicksort. Many implementations will use median of three to find a pivot, picking the median of the first, last and middle element in a sorted sequence, the median is the center, and the pivot will partition the input into two elements of roughly the same size (it might not be exact in the presence of duplicates for the middle element). Of course, there is *one* sorted worst case for median of three: all elements being the same. Also, `std::sort` often do *introsort* that will attempt quicksort or fallback to merge

Comment: just measured it, `std::stable_sort()` is a bit worse than `std::sort()` on unsorted data, and actually much worse on sorted data.